# Software center not opening (Segmentation fault)

Tags: software-center, segmentation-fault

```
usman@usmanPC:~$ software-center
2012-11-20 18:23:17,310 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2012-11-20 18:23:17,320 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2012-11-20 18:23:17,671 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2012-11-20 18:23:17,868 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
2012-11-20 18:23:17,928 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This type of problem is actually a bug, and is thus offtopic. It is recommended that you [file a bug report on Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) instead, providing all the details you have given here in addition to any that the developers may ask you for. Thanks!

Comment: As a temporary fix try issuing `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin` as indicated [here] (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=803215), on Ubuntu forums.